# QDialogs using layouts but with a fixed size (no size grip)

Tags: qt, dialog, cross-platform

I have several `QDialogs` that I have made in Qt Designer that use layouts, so the dialog can size itself correctly depending on the size of its children. The size of its children is run-time dependent (variable text fields, system font size etc).

It does not make sense for my dialog to be user-resizeable, so I want the size grip disabled. As far as I can tell, the size grip is disabled by calling `setFixedSize()`. However, I cannot put in a pixel size here, so I have implemented `resizeEvent()` like so:

```
void cRemoteConnectionDialog::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *)
{
    setFixedSize(minimumSize());
}
```

This works fine on Windows, but the dialog is far to small on Mac OS X.

How can I achieve a program resizable but not user resizeable `QDialog` that takes up the minimum space it requires based on run-time state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this on your dialog:

```
this->layout()->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize);
```